# Frictionless Materials and Survival

Tags: technology, armors

Dear Denizens of Worldbuilding:

I have hit upon a method of rendering a surface devoid of the forces of friction at will, then returning it to the normal operations of physics.

As exciting as this discovery is, it also means I have become the target for many malignant men.  I have currently been caged by said forces, until they can figure out a way to exploit my talents.

It is not terribly awful here, but the food is rather bland and it does get quite drafty.  In fact, escape would be quite easy, just walk down the road until I reach signs of humanity.  But in order to ensure my cooperation they have stationed gunmen for the next mile at regular intervals.

Therefore, your most magnificent mission is to figure out a method by which I can ensure my safety against a large variety of conventional weaponry.  I have a full suite of metal working equipment, multiple minions (their survival is secondary) of skill, and a fabricator capable of generating batteries and circuits of ten kilos or less.

Will my frictionless materials help in my escape?

Comment: Related, don't think it is a dupe http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/54041/17720

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the question to clarify I wanted to see about protection from conventional firearms

Comment: I think there are several properties people are going to need to know about the "friction-less" material. Friction-less does not mean force cant be applied to it, it just means any force not on a vector inwards to the material will flow tangentially along whatever plain the armor is on. Can this material withstand a bullet hitting it directly perpendicular?(the force will still fully transfer). How about concussive force? Does this material deform when force manages to get applied? What about heat? (is it a bad day if someone has a flame thrower?)

Comment: Ah, now that I am in possession of a true console of editing, I shall clarify a few points.

Comment: I've done some grammar and sentence re-structuring to the post. Feel free to decline if you don't like it or if it changes the meaning of your question in any way.

Comment: @Raisus, many thanks, I don't believe they did detract from the meaning of the question.

Comment: Before I try to answer this, is there any clarification on "why" is the material frictionless? Does it ignore electromagnetism? Does it have a perfectly smooth surface down to the atomic level? Is it just lubricated? etc. All these would affect the answer.

Comment: It appears to be a combination of atomic smoothing and ignoring of electromagnetic forces

Comment: And also what is this "generating batteries and circuits of ten kilos or less"? Kilos of what?

Comment: The total weight of the circutry and battery must weigh less than 10 kilos when fabricated.  Something of a size limit with these fabricators.

Comment: It only fabricates circuits? What raw materials do you have there?

Comment: I should clarify, it makes small to medium components though it only has blueprints of electrical engineering types.  I appear to have an unlimited supply of raw materials.

Comment: "How can my character achieve objective X using these items?" is a question about your story/plot, rather than the world that story occurs in. As such, this is off-topic for Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: I apologize, the situation is merely a hypothectical one designed to help explain the best use of frictionless materials in vehicular and personal armor.